# App Engine server + Android multiplayer game

Tags: google-app-engine

Greetings,

I'm creating a multi-player android game and thought it would be a interesting idea to have App Engine handle the server work.
The game consists of 4 players, each phone requests an update every 0.5 seconds.
These requests are very simple and lightweight so i shouldn't be over reaching any free quotas.
The problem i found was that App Engine only handles 500 requests per second, i would only be able to
have around 60 game sessions active before App Engine will start ignoring new requests?

"App Engine's quota system allows for efficient applications with billing enabled to scale to around 500 queries per second (qps) or more than 40 million queries per day."

Or should i just not use this platform because it is not made for this kind of usage?

I sent this same question to the discussion groups on google but after 4 hours it hasn't been posted, there was no response on whether it was a bad question or anything. Hopefully someone here can give me some advice.

Thank you kindly, i'm looking forward to an answer and or advice.
Greetings,
Rohan C

Comment: If you think you can do 500 QPS inside the free quota, I think you're being _extremely_ optimistic. 500 QPS is a lot of traffic.

Comment: I'm sorry but i absolutely do not know what to expect in terms of usage and quota, all i'm worried about at the moment is what will happen if at any point it will i exceed the 500 qps.
Also it's just a servlet with very simple database calls.
I'm a big amateur considering AppEngine and will take any advice i can get.

Comment: As I said, that's not a hard limit - in fact, it's not a limit anymore at all. As long as your requests take less than 1000 ms to execute, we'll automatically scale your app for you indefinitely. As commenters here and elsewhere have said, though, you really need to reconsider your approach: 2 requests per second isn't going to scale very well, is going to waste a lot of resources, and isn't likely to work for most mobile networks either.

Comment: @Nick, Thank you very very much for you're help,  I'l try and figure out a more manageable solution for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an interesting question, considering the only page where I can find that quote contains the answer in the same paragraph.

http://code.google.com/support/bin/request.py?contact_type=AppEngineCPURequest

> App Engine's quota system allows for
>   efficient applications with billing
>   enabled to scale to around 500 queries
>   per second (qps) or more than 40
>   million queries per day. This is a
>   substantial amount of traffic and
>   should easily suffice for even the
>   heaviest of Slashdottings. **But if you
>   expect your application will need to
>   handle even higher qps, please
>   complete this form so we can assist
>   you.**